# Create Table from Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry for silly title, but its really the outcome i am trying to achieve

I have a table in a workbook in sheet 1

i need to have an exact replica of that table in sheet 2 in the same workbook ,also i want the replica to dynamically update with any changes happening in the original table

My first thought was to create a table from the table, but that is not permitted, i tried to find a way to create a connection, but these are only valid with external sources

Is there any way to do that , without having to use formulas? like an inherent builtin feature that can do that

thanks in advance

Comment: Try the Camera feature. It won't be a replica, it will be a sort of live action image of your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `A1` of `Sheet 2` enter

```
=NameOfYourTable[#All]
```

<sub>Note: this requires a version of Excel that supports Spill ranges (eg Excel 365)</sub>

Comment: thank you this works